# How to give proper path to Pytorch model in Github?

Tags: github, pytorch, streamlit

My repo is like this

```
repo:
   model:
         fasterrcnn.pth
   streamlit.py
```

I am using

```
WEIGHTS_FILE = './model/fasterrcnn.pth'
```

and this to upload the model

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(WEIGHTS_FILE))
```

but error gives

```
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'.
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/streamlit/streamlit.py", line 71, in <module>
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(WEIGHTS_FILE, map_location=device))
File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 529, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 692, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
```

The app works on my desktop,
Thanks

Edit: I understood the question better, I have put the .pth that is 168 file in GitHub through git lfs, but it seems it can't run that big file in github

Comment: can you please add the code in which you try to load the model?

Comment: yes, I added it @TheodorPeifer